# Which web charting libraries export well with Wicked PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I've found a lot of SO questions about people having headaches with HighCharts and Flot exporting their HTML/JS/CSS charts to PDF with Wicked PDF, the Rails gem, but nothing about great successes. Has anyone successfully used a charting library to export with Wicked PDF and had a (relatively) headache-free experience? Specifically, I'm looking to make pie charts.

More generally, does anyone know if canvas or SVG or just page elements tend to render better on export?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with chart.js, which uses canvas, and Google charts and AmCharts, which use SVG, I found that the SVG rendering looked dramatically better, with canvas's raster-based rendering looking grainy and pixelated.